# Hosting my jars in Github with dependencies for Maven Repository

Tags: maven-2, maven, github, repository, maven-3

I am planning to host some of my API jars in Git hub as Maven Repository.

I have some 3rd party dependent jars needed with my jars.

When user like to pull my API i like the 3rd party dependent jars also downloaded to the local repository.  say the 3rd party jars are 5 and they are in different repository.

when user adds a dependency as my api with my githum repository url can maven automatically find api dependent jars and it fetch from different places into local repository ?

How can i do this ? do we have any way to do with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Maven would be able to download all the dependent jars (based on dependencies mentioned in POM xml in your API).

Answer (score 5):

This article describes the way to perform what you need: http://cemerick.com/2010/08/24/hosting-maven-repos-on-github/

This plugin can help you to automate such task: http://synergian.github.com/wagon-git/index.html

Comment: That article from cemerick is a good starting point.  I was able to automate the process here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14013645/82156