# How can I use maven project hosted at Google code as dependency?

Tags: maven, dependency-management, google-voice, maven-wagon-plugin

I want to create a maven project to depend on maven-structured Google Code project that has been frozen before they has been published to maven central repo.

Since their code is available ( http://code.google.com/p/google-voice-java/source/browse/branches/maven/pom.xml ), it has properly designed pom.xml that shows all their dependencies, I believe it would be a way to specify the path to their repo, and download their code and build their artifacts as a part of my building cycle. Alternatively, I should  download their jars, add to my local repo and add their dependencies to my dependencies list.

I googled much about it, but the only founding is wagon plugin, that makes opposite, it puts the build artifacts to google code repo turning it into a maven repo.

Please, advice!

Comment: I am currently looking forward for approaches to make Maven projects depend on source code instead of deployed binaries. I've found one [entry on Maven JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-1326) which proposes it but wasn't accepted as a new feature request. Alternative would be provide some plugin to accomplish that but I haven't found anything like this yet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the original link was permanently removed by Google. The question has no possible answer anymore, and neither could be interesting to anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project appears to be neither published to maven central nor google code's snapshot repo 
(https://code.google.com/p/google-maven-repository/wiki/ProjectSetup).

I would recommend either using:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=… -DpomFile=… -Dpackaging=jar
```

or

```
 mvn install:install-file -Dfile=... -DgroupId=... -DartifactId=... -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

This puts the artifact in your local repo directory (.../.m2/repository/) and makes it available for use in the dependencies section of your pom.xml.

Comment: so, there is now way to resolve this through configuring the pom.xml only? for my needs downloading the whole project code from the remote code repo, building it locally at my side is much more appropriate (while time-consuming) than doing manual install on each developer machine... or may be there is a way to specify jar file URL from downloads part of my pom.xml? I need to prepare maven project to be run from scratch on every machine with maven installed.

Comment: @IlyaYevlampiev one option is download the code, generate the binaries (jars and likely stuff) and provide it to other developers through GitHub. Checkout [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013644/hosting-a-maven-repository-on-github/14013645#14013645) for more information on this approach. Other alternatives: [upload to the Maven's repositories](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html); build from source through [JitPack](https://jitpack.io/); finally, you could also host binaries on [BinTray](https://bintray.com/).