# Gradle and github repository, slow sync

Tags: android, github, gradle

Since this morning, I have a strange problem on my android project on Android Studio. Gradle sync is very slow. I search and find that it is due to a github repositories.

I manage to reproduce this bug on a new android studio project with this build.gradle

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bbbenja/mvn-repo/master/' }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Github change its strategy on raw files ? Is anyone have the same problem ?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue-- our entire Android project would not build because we have a dependency on a Github hosted mvn repository.

This appears to be a problem with Github. It seems like their "raw" hosting isn't working.

This was my temporary workaround:

1) Git clone the repo locally

2) Use MAMP or another web server locally, point it to where you download the mvn-repo folder

3) In your build file, set it to localhost... according to your web server

For example this is what our build.gradle looks like now:

```
repositories {
    // this maven repo is a source for the compile dependencies

    //maven { url 'https://github.com/Goddchen/mvn-repo/raw/master/'}
    //temporary workaround
    maven { url 'http://localhost:8888/' }
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
    flatDir name: 'libs', dirs: "libs"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I finally upload all the librairies on my nexus and it works well now. I hope github will fix that.

Answer (score 1):

No need to clone git repo locally all you have to do is filter your repository fetching by following native Gradle support

Repository to dependency matching

It is now possible to match repositories to dependencies, so that Gradle doesn't search for a dependency in a repository if it's never going to be found there.

Example:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo.mycompany.com"
        content {
           includeGroupByRegex "com\\.mycompany.*"
        }
    }
}
```

for further reference [Gradle 5.1.1](https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/release-notes.html#repository-to-dependency-matching)