# Double Espresso not working with Robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric, android-testing, android-espresso

I'm trying to run Espresso (using [Double Espresso](https://github.com/JakeWharton/double-espresso)) via instrumentation testing and unit tests via Robolectric. What I have so far is largely based on the [deckard-gradle](https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle) example.

**Note:** Gradle 1.10

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.4'
    classpath 'org.robolectric.gradle:gradle-android-test-plugin:0.10.0'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'android-test'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 19
  buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'

  defaultConfig {
    packageName = 'com.example.app'
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0.0'
    testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
  }

  buildTypes {
    debug {
      debuggable = true
      runProguard = false
    }

    release {
      debuggable = false
      runProguard = true
    }
  }

  sourceSets {
    androidTest {
      setRoot('src/test')
    }
  }

  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
  }
}

androidTest {
  include '**/*Test.class'
  exclude '**/espresso/**/*.class'
  maxHeapSize = "2048m"
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'

  androidTestCompile('com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso:1.1-r3')
  androidTestCompile('com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso-support-v4:1.1-r3') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
  }

  androidTestCompile('junit:junit:4.11') {
    exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
  }
  androidTestCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3') {
    exclude module: 'classworlds'
    exclude module: 'maven-artifact'
    exclude module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
    exclude module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
    exclude module: 'maven-model'
    exclude module: 'maven-plugin-registry'
    exclude module: 'maven-profile'
    exclude module: 'maven-project'
    exclude module: 'maven-settings'
    exclude module: 'nekohtml'
    exclude module: 'plexus-container-default'
    exclude module: 'plexus-interpolation'
    exclude module: 'plexus-utils'
    exclude module: 'wagon-file'
    exclude module: 'wagon-http-lightweight'
    exclude module: 'wagon-http-shared'
    exclude module: 'wagon-provider-api'
  }
  androidTestCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.8'
}
```

My directory structure is as follows, where `com.example.app.espresso` needs to be run as `connectedAndroidTest` and `com.example.app.data` as `test`:

```
src
|- debug
|- main
|- release
|- test
   |- java
      |- com
         |- example
            |- app
               |- espresso
                  |- HomeActivityTest.java
               |- data
                  |- DataTest.java
   |- resources
      |- data_input.json
```

So when I run `gradle clean test`, I get errors not recognizing Espresso imports in `HomeActivityTest.java`.

When I run `gradle clean connectedAndroidTest`, I get errors not recognizing JUnit4 annotations in `DataTest.java` (`FailedToCreateTests.testSuiteConstructionFailed`).

If I take either part out (dependencies and sources), the other one works fine independently but not with everything included together.

**Note:** I tried importing Espresso jar's locally (no Double Espresso), same way deckard-gradle does it, which works until I use anything from the `support-v4` library in the Espresso test (`com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso-support-v4` appears to solve that, which there is no alternative for with local jar's), then it explodes into `FailedToCreateTests.testSuiteConstructionFailed`.

Has anyone got this structure working? Is there any way to exclude source paths from each target?

Any solutions (full or partial) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I abandoned the idea of using Double Espresso and going with the approach that deckard-gradle takes - manually importing the Espresso jar's (`espresso`, `testrunner` and `testrunner-runtime`).

It appears that either Double Espresso is doing more than just wrapping the jar's as aar's and hosting them or the fact that they are aar's causes problems. Would be interested to know why.

To avoid keeping local dependencies, I uploaded the Espresso jar's to a Maven repo, daisy-chained them (`espresso` depends on `testrunner-runtime`, `testrunner-runner` depends on `testrunner`) and included all the third-party dependencies (Guava, Hamcrest, Dagger etc) in the POM. If you don't have a hosted Maven repo, you can use GitHub as your repo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14013645/818393.

Admittedly, not the best solution but it works.

Comment: Nice solution. I forked your repository to include a rebuilt version of espresso that utilizes Dagger 1.2 here: https://github.com/tommyd3mdi/mvn

Comment: This works well unless you're using Dagger 1.2 in your project. :(

Answer (score 5):

This is occurring because the Double Espresso artifacts are distributed as .aar files and the compile task that Robolectric generates for running the tests does not depend upon a task that unpackages .aar files that are part of the androidTestCompile dependency configuration.

Since you typically won't run your espresso tests as part of the task that runs your unit tests, you can safely exclude the espresso tests from the compilation task generated by the Robolectric plugin.  I do this by adding a dependency to the compilation task generated by the Robolectric plugin to my build.gradle that touches up the source property.  Example code below.  Make sure to touch up the name of the robolectric generated compile task ('compileTestDebugJava' in my example) and your 'exclude' for your espresso tests as necessary.

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { theTask ->
    if ("compileTestDebugJava".toString().equals(theTask.name.toString())) {
        def cleanupTask = "touchUpRobolectricSourceSet"
        project.task(cleanupTask) << {
            FileTree tree = fileTree(dir: 'src/test/java')
            tree.exclude '**/espresso/**/*.java'

            theTask.source = tree
        }
        theTask.dependsOn(cleanupTask)
    }
}
```

Comment: I needed to modify this to handle my different build flavors. In case it's of any help to others: https://gist.github.com/loeschg/3ce24c34dec364270ab8

Comment: For various reasons, I've abandoned the above approach in favor of keeping my Robolectric tests in a Gradle submodule.  You can find a blog post I wrote about why I moved in this direction and a fork of the deckard-gradle project that shows you how here: https://github.com/jdonmoyer/deckard-gradle

Comment: I've also done the same and am very happy to have done so. It's much cleaner. I followed this: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/android-gradle-app-with-robolectric-junit-tests/

Comment: Is there any reason why you are calling toString() on "compileTestDebugJava"? Isn't this redundant?

Comment: @JoshFeldman probably a simple copy/paste/replace error on my part.  If I remember correctly, when I was actually using this in my project, the task I was testing wasn't hardcoded but was dynamically retrieved based on build flavor

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, seems to be the fault of Dagger 1.2 (included as a dependency in Jake's double espresso). If you include the plain 1.1 libraries it should work.

(Full thread here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robolectric/xeLrnCAsq5Q)

Comment: Hi, Thomas, thanks for your answer. Downgrading Dagger and also adding the `support-v4` exclusion to all the test imports (including `fest-android` and `robolectric`) fixed the `androidTest` target, however when trying to run the Robolectric tests, it still doesn't exclude the Espresso tests and compilation fails because it cannot find Espresso classes... Any ideas?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Thats why its also still a blocker for me. I guess we have to live with separate test sources for now.