# add jar to central maven repository

Tags: maven, repository

I have just finished a project which i put on github- it is a library i hope others can use. 
I want to generate a jar from this project and make it available to other people and other projects via maven. Just wondering what the best way of making the project available through maven is?
I would like it to be as simple as adding the following to pom.xml for the end user:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.mylibraryproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>mylibrary</artifactId>
  <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make Maven repository on github.
This example is shown in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013644/hosting-a-maven-repository-on-github).