# Hosting maven repository in Github

Tags: git, maven, github

I am trying to host a new maven repository in Github, but I keep on getting this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.github:site-maven-plugin:0.9:site (default) on project app-name: Server 'github' not found in settings -> [Help 1]
```

I sure have the this in settings.xml

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>github</id>
    <username>user</username>
    <password>pass</password>
  </server>
</servers>
```

Comment: Have you setup pom.xml?

Comment: Have you seen [Hosting a Maven repository on github](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013644/hosting-a-maven-repository-on-github)?

Comment: Yes I saw it, not sure why it doesn't work now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `~/.m2/settings.xml` has to be like this:

```
<settings>
 <servers>
   <server>
    <id>github</id>
    <username>user</username>
    <password>pass</password>
   </server>
 </servers>
</settings>
```

Comment: Yes I have this setting