# Using Dropbox as Maven Repository

Tags: java, maven, dropbox

Since the Github plugin for hosting maven repositories within Github is not working anymore, I am trying to find some other quick way to host a maven artifact.

One way I am thinking is to use my Dropbox 'Public' folder (since I still have it active now) and host the artifact from there.

- What could be the approach to use Dropbox as maven repository?
- Is there a plugin to use Dropbox as maven repository?

Comment: What about bintray.com ?

Comment: I tried bintray, however it does have some soft of approval and they don't accept SNAPSHOT versions, I think bintray are for releases only

Comment: I use sonatype. It supports snapshots.

Comment: For the record, deploying maven artifacts to GitHub does work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013644/hosting-a-maven-repository-on-github  I'm doing exactly that and I am able to deploy and fetch artifacts from my GitHub repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For people who share a common Dropbox folder, you can set it up as a Maven repository using this configuration in your project/pom.xml or maven/conf/settings.xml:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>localDropbox</id>
        <url>file://[path to Dropbox folder]</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

And to use `mvn deploy` to send artifacts there:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>localDropbox</id>
        <url>file://[path to Dropbox folder]</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

If the folder is publicly available, people who want access to that could have a http URL instead of filesystem URL in their `<repository>` declaration.