# Fail upload jar into github with maven

Tags: java, git, maven, github

I try to follow : [Hosting a Maven repository on github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013644/hosting-a-maven-repository-on-github/)

My POM.xml

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>rf</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.zlhades</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>rfcore</artifactId>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <github.global.server>github</github.global.server>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.github</groupId>
            <artifactId>site-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.12</version>
            <configuration>
                <message>Maven artifacts for ${project.version}</message>  <!-- git commit message -->
                <noJekyll>true</noJekyll>                                  <!-- disable webpage processing -->
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/mvn-repo</outputDirectory> <!-- matches distribution management repository url above -->
                <branch>refs/heads/mvn-repo</branch>                       <!-- remote branch name -->
                <includes><include>**/*</include></includes>
                <repositoryName>RequestForward</repositoryName>      <!-- github repo name -->
                <repositoryOwner>zlhades</repositoryOwner>    <!-- github username  -->
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <!-- run site-maven-plugin's 'site' target as part of the build's normal 'deploy' phase -->
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>site</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


    </plugins>
</build>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>internal.repo</id>
        <name>Temporary Staging Repository</name>
        <url>file://${project.build.directory}/mvn-repo</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2-beta</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And I got below error:

> =========================log==========================
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   com.github.github:site-maven-plugin:0.12:site (default) on project
>   rfcore: Error creating commit: Invalid request.
>
> [ERROR] For 'properties/name', nil is not a string.
>
> [ERROR] For 'properties/name', nil is not a string. (422)
>
> [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
>
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal com.github.github:site-maven-plugin:0.12:site (default)
>   on project rfcore: Error creating commit: Invalid request.
>
> For 'properties/name', nil is not a string.
>
> For 'properties/name', nil is not a string. (422)
>   =========================log==========================

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thx, I found the answer:
The comment at the bottom of this post suggests that you need to have filled in the Real Name field in your github profile to avoid this error.

https://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2014/03/10/create-simple-maven-repository-on-github/