# Maven Deploy Command

Tags: maven

Here I just tried to deploy my simple maven project to git hub.I added some more plugins for deploying.I can compile,and package that.While deploying still i'm facing some errors.Please help me to resolve this.Can you give any idea for deploy a maven project from eclipse.

```
C:\MavApp\MavDep>mvn clean deploy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MavDep 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ MavDep ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\MavApp\MavDep\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ MavDep ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\MavApp\MavDep\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ MavDep ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\MavApp\MavDep\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ MavDep ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\MavApp\MavDep\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ MavDep ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\MavApp\MavDep\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ MavDep ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\MavApp\MavDep\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.MavDep.AppTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.015 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ MavDep ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\MavApp\MavDep\target\MavDep-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ MavDep ---
[INFO] Installing C:\MavApp\MavDep\target\MavDep-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\mstemp 401\.m2\repository\com\MavDep\MavDep\1.0-SNAPSHOT\MavDep-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\MavApp\MavDep\pom.xml to C:\Users\mstemp 401\.m2\repository\com\MavDep\MavDep\1.0-SNAPSHOT\MavDep-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ MavDep ---
Downloading: file://C:\MavApp\MavDep\target/mvn-repo/com/MavDep/MavDep/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Uploading: file://C:\MavApp\MavDep\target/mvn-repo/com/MavDep/MavDep/1.0-SNAPSHOT/MavDep-1.0-20170412.080139-1.jar
Uploaded: file://C:\MavApp\MavDep\target/mvn-repo/com/MavDep/MavDep/1.0-SNAPSHOT/MavDep-1.0-20170412.080139-1.jar (3 KB at 78.8 KB/sec)
Uploading: file://C:\MavApp\MavDep\target/mvn-repo/com/MavDep/MavDep/1.0-SNAPSHOT/MavDep-1.0-20170412.080139-1.pom
Uploaded: file://C:\MavApp\MavDep\target/mvn-repo/com/MavDep/MavDep/1.0-SNAPSHOT/MavDep-1.0-20170412.080139-1.pom (2 KB at 121.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: file://C:\MavApp\MavDep\target/mvn-repo/com/MavDep/MavDep/maven-metadata.xml
Uploading: file://C:\MavApp\MavDep\target/mvn-repo/com/MavDep/MavDep/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Uploaded: file://C:\MavApp\MavDep\target/mvn-repo/com/MavDep/MavDep/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (760 B at 23.2 KB/sec)
Uploading: file://C:\MavApp\MavDep\target/mvn-repo/com/MavDep/MavDep/maven-metadata.xml
Uploaded: file://C:\MavApp\MavDep\target/mvn-repo/com/MavDep/MavDep/maven-metadata.xml (274 B at 17.8 KB/sec)
[INFO]
[INFO] --- site-maven-plugin:0.11:site (default) @ MavDep ---
[INFO] Creating 12 blobs
[INFO] Creating tree with 12 blob entries
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 15.161 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-12T13:31:51+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/160M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.github:site-maven-plugin:0.11:site (default) on project MavDep: Error creating commit: Invalid request.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For 'properties/name', nil is not a string.
[ERROR] For 'properties/name', nil is not a string. (422)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220177/fail-upload-jar-into-github-with-maven

Comment: The problem is the gibhub site plugin which is bound to the deploy cycle which is simply wrong if you do a `mvn deploy` it should not being executed...

Comment: Do you want to build a project and put the resulting artifacts on github?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in your maven properties the name is incorrect. Check your pom.xml file.
If this is not the case, try running it with the -e switch on

Comment: I'm also try to execute with -e switch that also displaying the errors.Can you please share the exact command for deploy..\

Comment: The problem is not in your command but in your pom.xml file. Look for the tag <name>...</name>. Can you tell me what is in there?

Comment: The following one is the part of  pom.xml file

Comment: <groupId>com.MavDep</groupId>
  <artifactId>MavDep</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>MavDep</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

Comment: Then you should probably take a look at the first comment by @alpert and follow the link