# Zoho Java library

Tags: maven, maven-3, zoho

I found this link for Zoho Java library:

```
https://github.com/zoho/projects-java-wrappers

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.zoho.projects</groupId>
  <artifactId>projects-java</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Where I can find public repository where this jar file is hosted?

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no public repository for the project. Here [Hosting a Maven repository on github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013644/hosting-a-maven-repository-on-github) you can read more about github as maven repository.

I chosen a JitPack approach and I checked that solution described on https://jitpack.io/#zoho/projects-java-wrappers/ac2b31602f works.

JitPack is kind of self release maven repository

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.zoho</groupId>
    <artifactId>projects-java-wrappers</artifactId>
    <version>ac2b31602f</version>
</dependency>
```