# Maven doesn't update Github repository

Tags: java, maven, github

I'm using a github repository with jitpack with the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.bys1</groupId>
  <artifactId>taigalib</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

For some reason, after updating from version 1.1 to 1.2 and later 1.2.1, it doesn't update the class eu.taigacraft.lib.sql.MySQL. In 1.2 and 1.2.1 the methods createStatement(), get(String) and update(String) were added. After updating to 1.2 and later 1.2.1 I'm not able to use that methods; the don't exist. I've tried the following:

- Project clean
- Maven update
- Using Github commit id instead of release tag as version
- Waiting for hours and refreshing

I'd like to know why it doesn't load the new methods and how I can solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013644/hosting-a-maven-repository-on-github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Are you using jitpack repository?

<repository>
  <id>jitpack.io</id>
  <url>https://jitpack.io/</url>
</repository>

Also try deleting the existing jar file of 1.1 version and then updating maven project and compiling it.
```

You could find the jar via somthing like: sudo find / -name '*1.1*jar'