# using a private github repository to host a private maven artifact

Tags: maven, github, dependencies, repository, private

Question title kind of explains it all. I've seen other questions referencing this but I think they are more geared towards the github repository being public. Using this configuration in the dependent project works when the repository is public:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>company-core-mvn-repo</id>
        <url>https://raw.github.com/company/company-core/mvn-repo/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>company-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But not when I change the settings to private. I was hoping someone could eplicitly tell me that this isn't possible before I try another approach. It seems strange that the dependency has no issues publishing to github yet I can't find a configuration that will allow the dependent package to pull it down.

Comment: Just to check and verify: 
1. you cleand your m2 repo folder before you check your settings and  
2. do you tried also: 
<releases>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
 </releases> 
in your repository? Because the version is no SNAPSHOT version you refer to

Comment: not sure what your question is. Authentication is put in the settings.xml file outside your project - usually $HOME/.m2/ - it contains a <servers> section that refers to the id of your repository to configure authentication.