# neo4j cypher dsl 3.0.6 jar not present in maven repo

Tags: maven, cypher, querydsl

I am planning to use neo4j-cypher-dsl
     < https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/cypher-dsl >
 as a dependency in my project. The latest version in this git repo is 3.0.6 and I neither find it in maven repository nor in http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-dsl/
I want to be sure that its not available anywhere in maven repos before I build the jar myself. Below is the snippet from my pom.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-dsl</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
</dependency>
 <repositories> 
    <repository> 
        <id>neo4j-public</id> 
        <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/groups/public</url> 
    </repository> 
    <repository>
        <id>neo4j-contrib-releases</id>
        <url>https://raw.github.com/neo4j-contrib/m2/master/releases</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>neo4j-contrib-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://raw.github.com/neo4j-contrib/m2/master/snapshots</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not available anywhere. The MVN Repository site does a pretty good job at indexing repositories and it only points to the [2.3.x versions](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-cypher-dsl) that you also found.

Just build it, it only takes a couple of minutes with tests. If you would like to use it from a CI build and do not want to build this dependency each time, you can deploy the binaries to (preferably) a private GitHub repository. You can then use the GitHub Pages feature to host a [Maven repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013644/hosting-a-maven-repository-on-github) (you may also skip authentication). However, many consider this as bad practice and it's easy to see why: GitHub Pages was designed to serve simple static web pages (e.g. docs) and not binaries.

Comment: Thanks Gabor. May be I am asking a naive question here. Building a jar gave a single jar . What about the dependencies ?

Comment: This depends on how you use that JAR file. If you install it to your local Maven repository (to the `~/.m2` directory, using the `mvn clean install` command), the JARs dependencies will also be installed. If you want to use it as a standalone JAR file (i.e. without Maven), you will have to include all transitive dependencies - but this is generally not recommended.