# how to host a maven on github and gitlab?

Tags: android, maven, github, gradle, aar

I found a way to do this :

[Hosting a Maven repository on github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013644/hosting-a-maven-repository-on-github/14013645#14013645)

But when I Archives a aar for a Android Library,It always can't found!

I was use the gradle to archives:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        repository(url: "file:///Users/kycq/repo")
        pom.project {
            groupId "com.test"
            artifactId "widget"
            version project.android.defaultConfig.versionName
        }
    }
}
```

How to archives the aar to maven on github and gitlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal `maven` plugin does not work for android builds. Use this plugin instead: https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin

Have a look at these projects for some working examples:

- https://github.com/jitpack/android-example
- https://github.com/freefair/android-colors