# Maven: non lifecycle-related goal

Tags: maven

I have project for which you need to have a few dependency downloadable from an internal repo.
If this is not possible I'd like to provide an option to install the deps locally (using maven-install-plugin).
Point is: since this is fully optional I do not want this to be part of the regular lifecycle (I've seen solutions where the install plugin is executed in the clean phase). Which is the terser and more elegant way to provide an option to install prerequisites locally?

Comment: Maybe this link, showning how to store artifacts in git, will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013644/hosting-a-maven-repository-on-github